# Graph is not being displayed in my html-Django (embedding dynamic graph in html)

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to generate a graph, but I am not able to view the picture embedded in my html file.

. This is my view file:

```
def report(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            course = form.cleaned_data['course']
            course1 = str(json.dumps(list(course)))
            t = course1
            course_selected = ((t.replace('"',"")).replace('[',"")).replace(']',"")
            values = Article.objects.filter(body=course_selected).values_list('likes')
            v1=str(values)
            v2=v1.replace('(',"").replace(')',"").replace(',,',"").replace(',',"").replace('[',"").replace(']',"")
            num1=map(int,v2.split(" "))


            fig=Figure()
            ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
            x=[1,2,3]
            y=num1

            ax.plot(x,y)

            canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
            response= HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
            canvas.print_png(response)
            return response
else:
    form = ArticleForm()

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))

args['form'] = form

return render_to_response('report.html', args)

def report_graph(request):
name = 'Mike'
return render_to_response('report_graph.html',{'name':name})
```

This is my html file. The first one is when the form is being generated:
    {% extends "base.html"%}

```
{% block sidebarinfo %}

<div style="text-align: center;">
    <h2> Course Selection</h2>
    <form action = "/articles/report/" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}

    <ul>
    {{form.as_ul}}
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate Report" />



{% endblock %}
```

The second is where I want to see the graph embedded

```
{% extends "base.html"%}

{% block sidebarinfo %}

<div style="text-align: center;">



    <img src = "/articles/report/report.png" />


</div>


{% endblock %}
```

In case you want to see, this is my url file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^all/$','article.views.articles'),
                       url(r'^get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.article'),
                       url(r'^language/(?P<language>[a-z\-]+)/$', 'article.views.language'),
                       url(r'^create/$', 'article.views.create'),
                       url(r'^like/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.like_article'),
                       url(r'^search/$', 'article.views.search_titles'),
                       url(r'^report/report.png','article.views.report'),
                       url(r'^report/$','article.views.report_graph'),
                       )
```

***The problem I am facing is, no image is being shown in my html. I know the graph is being generated because if I set the form to go directly to the graph image it work. However, when I try embedding that source into my html script, nothing comes up.I hope this makes sense. If there is a better way to embed a graph, I am willing to do that***

Answer (score 1):

When the html loads, the browser will do a `GET` request for the image base on the url that your provide in your `src` attribute.

In your current view you have placed your graphing code under the post request.

```
def report(request):
    if request.POST: ##<<---- the request is  not post therefore your image will not load
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            course = form.cleaned_data['course']
            course1 = str(json.dumps(list(course)))
            t = course1
            course_selected = ((t.replace('"',"")).replace('[',"")).replace(']',"")
            values = Article.objects.filter(body=course_selected).values_list('likes')
            v1=str(values)
            v2=v1.replace('(',"").replace(')',"").replace(',,',"").replace(',',"").replace('[',"").replace(']',"")
            num1=map(int,v2.split(" "))


            fig=Figure()
            ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
            x=[1,2,3]
            y=num1

            ax.plot(x,y)

            canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
            response= HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
            canvas.print_png(response)
            return response
else:
    form = ArticleForm()
```

There are a few solutions to your problem .

One is to write a different view for it. But since you need the information from the post request, I will suggest that you

1. Plot the image and save it into media directory and load the image from there.
2. Save the data in the post view and write a 2nd view/or a if `request.get` to return the graph instead.
3. Otherwise, learn a javascript graphing library, d3 and c3 are good place to start and get django to return the values.

Let me know if you need any more help or more details.

Cheers,
Biobirdman

Comment: No worries, the biggest problem here is that your view is expecting a post request but the src in html is doing a get request.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something similar to what @biobirdman suggested. Perhaps the simplest way that I have found in displaying dynamically created graph content is by creating a separate view for the graph and using an image tag within your HTML view that will show the graph via the defined view URL.

You could use the `report` view that you have to handle the form and then if the `Article` model has an `article_name` for example, you could save that name in a session which can then be accessed via a separate view that generates the graph.

The `graph` view then plots and displays the graph which can be linked to a designated URL. Then within your desired HTML template you can reference that URL with an image tag like below:

```
<img src="{% url 'graph' %}" />
```

This assumes that within your URL you have `name="graph"`.

This is just another possibility. Ultimately it's dependent on your project and situation on which approach is the simplest or most elegant.